# Ruby array interpolation

Tags: ruby

I noticed the difference in printing array with and without interpolation:

**Source code:**

```
uuu="a b c d e f g";
o=uuu.split(' ');

puts "Interpolation:#{o}";

puts "Without interpolation";
puts o;
```

**Output:**

```
Interpolation:["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
Without interpolation
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
```

I don't understand why those differences happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `puts` in the main context without an explicit receiver, you are calling `Kernel#puts`, and that calls `$stdout.puts`. Usually, `$stdout.puts` outputs the result of applying `to_s` to its argument. However, array is exceptional in that each element of it is printed in a separate line. From [the doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-puts):

> *puts(obj, ...) → nil*
>   Writes the given objects to ios as with IO#print. Writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. **If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.** If called without arguments, outputs a single record separator.

In your first example, you interpolated a string with an array, which applies `to_s` to it, and ends up with a string of the format `["a", "b", ...]`, which is passed to `puts`. In your second example, you passed an array directly to `puts`, to which the exceptional behaviour on arrays explained above applies.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really have anything to do with how interpolation behaves. It's not interpolation that's giving you a difference in output, it's that your supply a string vs an array to `puts`.

The same results occur if you simply do this:

```
puts o.to_s
puts o
```

`puts` handles strings and arrays differently. In the first instance, you're giving it a string, into which an array has been interpolated. Interpolation invokes `to_s` on the value being interpolated, and when you invoke `to_s` on an array, it gives you the format you see in your output. For example `[1, 2, 3].to_s` is the string `"[1, 2, 3]"`.

When you give `puts` an array as its argument, it prints the items in the array, one per line.

Comment: Inside `"#{..}`.. we can also put chunk of code.. It evaluated.. Does that mean there also `#to_s` applied. So I think your *interpolation* explanation not correct..

Comment: @ArupRakshit Yes, and the result of your chunk of code has `to_s` invoked on it, unless it evaluates to a string. See http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/c14be

Comment: @ArupRakshit Try: `class Fixnum; def to_s; "WHAT"; end; end; puts "#{3 * 4}"`

Comment: I tested the same but differently - `class Fixnum
  undef to_s
end

"#{1}" # => NoMethodError)`... You are correct.

Comment: @ArupRakshit and meagar: `ruby -e 'class Fixnum; def to_s; "WHAT"; end; end; puts 42.to_s; puts "#{3 * 4}"'` Output: `WHAT` and `12`.

Comment: @DarekNędza Cannot reproduce in 1.8.7, 1.9.3, 2.0 or 2.1 All print "WHAT WHAT". Are you using something like JRuby?

Comment: @DarekNędza No I got the expected output "WHAT" "WHAT" ( 2 separate lines).

Comment: @ArupRakshit and maegar: I have tested it on`193: ruby 1.9.3p392` and `200: ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22)`. Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/nedzadarek/8e80077e9e0c61052e15 It seems that backticks (`\``) are weird.